# Update NSError UserInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, nserror

I'm trying to update an `NSError` object with more information.  For example, an api call may fail and I want to update the error object returned from the api class with view controller information (method name that caused error, client message, any additional info).  There isn't a setter method for the `UserInfo` dictionary and trying to set a value for the dictionary raises an exception (Not key value code compliant I believe).  I thought about creating a new `NSError` object with the updated user info, but I wasn't sure if I might lose information.

#### Question

What's the best way to update the user info dictionary of an NSError object?

Comment: What about merging existing userInfo with yours one?

Comment: The only way I could think to do this was to create a new NSError instance, but I wasn't sure if this would cause me to lose any data from the original NSError object.  How would you suggest merging the userinfo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest way to do this would be to get a mutable copy of the `userInfo` dictionary and add whatever you like to that. Then you would have to create a new `NSError` (since there is not setUserInfo: method) with the same domain and code as the original one.

Comment: Will I lose any other details doing this?

Comment: Just be careful not to use any of the keys listed in the [Constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001704-CJBIAHGF) section of NSError documentation otherwise you could end up overwriting existing info.

Comment: I'm using Flurry and Flurry expects an NSError class when logging errors. I had a custom error object before, but it was causing logging problems.

Comment: ipmcc's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18407304/2613662) is the best approach to this problem.

Comment: I agree.  I like ipmcc's approach, but it's heavy handed for what I need to do.  Your approach is inefficient, but simple and I won't have a bunch of nested NSErrors.

Answer (score 13):

With swift extentions it's easy:

```
extension NSError {

  func addItemsToUserInfo(newUserInfo: Dictionary<String, String>) -> NSError {

    var currentUserInfo = userInfo
    newUserInfo.forEach { (key, value) in
      currentUserInfo[key] = value
    }
    return NSError(domain: domain, code: code, userInfo: currentUserInfo)
  }
}
```

usage:

```
var yourError = NSError(domain: "com.app.your", code: 999, userInfo: nil)
yourError = yourError.addItemsToUserInfo(["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"])
```

Answer (score 8):

The canonical approach would be to make a new `NSError` all your own and then put the original `NSError` in the `userInfo` dictionary under the key `NSUnderlyingErrorKey`. This is a slightly different result, but as best I can tell `NSErrors` are quite intentionally immutable.

Comment: I like this approach, but it's overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish (set the display message if it wasn't set in the api) and will cause me headaches down the road.

Comment: @ipmcc could you explain the reason for that immutability? Nowhere is said about reasons. (In truth I didn't succeed in finding any information about that)